ASP.NET Core 8 MVC web app : scaffolding not working as expected
I'm migrating a project from ASP.NET Core 3.1 to ASP.NET Core 8.0. I created a new project (targeting .NET 8) and copied the folders, classes, model, controller and view files into the new project folder.
When compiling the new project, I get errors on all views. An example of one of the errors is:

The type or namespace name 'Models' does not exist in the namespace 'Samadhi.Pages.Samadhi' (are you missing an assembly reference?).
D:\PROJECTS_VS\MyWebsite_2024\Samadhi\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor.Compiler.SourceGenerators\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.RazorSourceGenerator\Views_Rbk_VideoFiles_cshtml.g.cs

I tried basic things like Clean, Build, Rebuilds, etc. but that did nothing.
https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/14zd7zp/brand_new_default_aspnet_core_mvc_8_project/
I tried the steps shown in the link above - a post that sounded like a similar issue - however, this had no effect.
The steps in the above post were:

Install the Nuget Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation
In Program.cs append builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews() with .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()

Can anyone shed some light on what is causing this problem?
Error list

When I open view 'VideosFiles.cshtml' the compiler doesn't recognize the 'Models' namespace. 'Samadhi' is the name of the project and the primary namespace. When I look at the popup error I don't know what 'Samadhi.Pages.Samadhi' refers to. There is no folder or namespace in my project called 'Pages'.

But the namespace & class are in the project:
namespace Samadhi.Models.Rbk
{
    public class DownloadFiles
    {
        public class FileInfo
        {
            public string FilePath { get; set; }
            public string FileName { get; set; }
            public string FileExtension { get; set; }
        }
        public List<FileInfo> video_files { get; set; }
    }    
}

Project file
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Samadhi\" />
    <Folder Include="Views\Shared\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="DeviceDetector.NET" Version="6.3.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="QRCoder" Version="1.4.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Stripe.net" Version="43.22.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

Project explorer


Usually these problems are caused by something else. I searched for the issue and for example invalid using statement can cause similar issues. It is a bit hard to narrow down reasons with this information. Did you try to close VS, remove .vs folder and start again? Is the first/last exception in solution related to same error?

@PanuOksala yes I agree. I've updated the post with screenshot of error list and project file contents. I have closed VS, removed .vs folder, etc., but no joy. All the exceptions are of the same type.

Thanks. I will try to crack this tomorrow. I have seen lots of similar issues, I just need to make very educated guess here

Can you please share a full repro somewhere? Have you tried building app with dotnet build command?

make sure that the @using directive in your .cshtml files matches the actual namespace where your models are located. If your models are in Samadhi.Models, then your @using directive at the top of the .cshtml files should be @using Samadhi.Models.check _ViewImports.cshtml file has the correct @using directives for your  models. check all the  .cshtml files located in a Pages folder. Manually delete the bin and obj folders and rebuild the project. Try explicitly referencing the model classes in your views with their full namespaces.

Try removing this from project file:




@JalpaPanchal none of my View files have any '@using...' statement in them. is there some new rule that requires this in .NET 8.0? I copied all the View files (.cshtml) from my Core 3.1 project, which compiles fine and there are no using statements at the top or anywhere else in the file. the only @ directives in the files are for views that use models. For example '@model Samadhi.Models.Shop'

@JalpaPanchal all my View files (.cshtml) are in a folder called "Views" not "Pages". I created an ASP.NET MVC project which automatically creates the "View" folder. I have several folders and View files under the "Views" folder.

@JalpaPanchal thx for your comment. it helped me to see what was wrong. I didn't check  the _ViewImports file. For some inexplicable reason it had "@namespace Samadhi.Pages", but should have just been "@namespace Samadhi".

@RossKelly glad my comment helped you to resolve the issue. i would like to suggest you post your solution as an answer and mark it so it will help other user in future if they face similar issue
